# Center a CSS box with the text next to it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use CSS to align boxed text next to some regular text, and am using  tags to create the boxed text.  If the box has text, then it's center-aligned with the regular text, but if the box is empty, then it is bottom-aligned.  Is there a way to always keep the boxes center-aligned with the text?

```css
#round,
#score {
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin solid dimgray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
Round # <a id=round></a> Your Score <a id=score>12345</a>
```

Please refer to the following JSBin for an illustration of my question: [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/duhitexuqa/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `vertical-align:middle` property

```css
#round,
#score {
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin solid dimgray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
Round # <a id=round></a> Your Score <a id=score>12345</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the **a** tag in a div as:

```
<div class="vcenter">
    Round # <a id=round></a> Your Score  <a id=score>12345</a>
  </div>
```

And apply this css

```
#round, #score {
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin solid dimgray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.vcenter{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center
}
```